# Auto-scroll not working for iframe in Chrome

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook App where if the user gets an error popup, the page is supposed to auto-scroll to a certain section (read center) of the page. I have got it working on Firefox, IE, Safari but cannot get it to work on Google Chrome.

Right now I'm using this code :

- document.getElementById('banner').scrollIntoView(true);

  --> works on all the major browsers except Chrome

I  have tried all the below functions to get it working on Chrome but no luck:

- 1.window.scrollTo(100,500);
- 2.parent.window.scroll(0,0);
- 3.parent.frames.window.scrollTo(200,300);
- 4.var rowpos = jQuery('#banner').position();
- 5.jQuery('#iframe_canvas').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#banner').offset().top  }, { duration: 'slow', easing:
  'swing'});

Since this is to be made to work on a Facebook App that is by rendered by Facebook in an iframe which is sort of like a sandbox, therefore the outermost parent window has no control of the elements inside the iframe, therefore I am running out of ideas.

I would really appreciate if anyone can drop any pointers to help me solve this issue, its holding up my entire project from being delivered :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors in the console? The fact that "nothing" is working would indicate that there's some other error condition occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FB.Canvas.scrollTo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/) function of the Facebook JS-SDK

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Frederick Behrends.
It's really helpfull for me.